# Placement of reference list

Tags: bibliographies, positioning

I'm writing a quite small report, in which I use a pair of references declared as bibitems directly in the document as below.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{title}
Title and author
\end{thebibliography}
```

I want the last section of the report to be an appendix with some figures (which are inserted using 'here'-placement). But, my problem is that the reference-list is rendered after the first image in the appendix, instead of before the appendix. How can I decide the placement of the reference list?

Below is a shortened version of my document (since it's good stackexchange-practice and it's impossible to render it exactly without the image-files anyway). This actually renders as I want to, but with more text and correct images it's rendered as described before.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{
Title
}

\author{
}

\begin{document}
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\vert#1\vert}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\maketitle

\section{Preface}
\subsection{Summary}

\subsection{Another section}
Some more text and an equation.
$$
F(s) = 4 \cdot \frac{ 2s+1 }{ 3s + 1 }
$$

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6cm]{fig1}
\caption{A caption}
\label{fig:gk}
\end{figure}

Some text

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{title1}
  Author and title
\bibitem{title2}
  Title and author
\end{thebibliography}

\section{Appendix: Diagrams}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=\textwidth]{pic1}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:gk}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=\textwidth]{pic2}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:gk}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=\textwidth]{pic3}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:gk}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thebibliography` and the `\section` that makes the appendix do not float, they just appear where they appear in the source. So if you want the references section before your appendix, just place the environment in that position. If that doesn't address the issue you'll need to supply a complete document MWE

Comment: At first, it didn't seem to make any difference, but it must've been a preview-issue because it works now. So simple! :)

Comment: @nico :don't forget to upvote the answer to thank David

Comment: Haven't suficcient rep to upvote on Tex-stackexchange yet...